# Podfile.lock missing when initial react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I am setting up IOS dev for React Native (0.61) app which has the working android version. What I did was to copy src of components and package.json file after react native environment is setup by following online post (installed xcode command line tool 10.2). But launching run-ios failed:

```
$ react-native run-ios
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
error Could not find the following native modules: RNCAsyncStorage, RNDeviceInfo, RNGestureHandler, RNKeychain, BVLinearGradient, RNLocalize, RNReanimated, RNVectorIcons, react-native-video. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
info Found Xcode project "emps_fe6.xcodeproj"
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Could not parse the simulator list output. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json devices
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnSimulator (/Usersamine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:130:54)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:100:12)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:23)
    at Command.listener (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/amine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:237:24)
```

Here is the output of react native info:

```
$ react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2675QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 194.93 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.17.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  IDEs:
    Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Here is the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.11.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
    "simctl": "^2.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.1.1",
    "xcode": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

In the error message, there mentioned quite a few modules which are missing. But those modules have been installed as it shows in the package.json. I am not sure about what the error message means. Also I installed the `simctl` but `scrum simctl` still can not find it. I am using VS Code as IDE.

UPDATE:

created an empty `Podfile.lock` under /ios, the error becomes when run-ios:

```
error Cannot read property 'SPEC CHECKSUMS' of undefined. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'SPEC CHECKSUMS' of undefined
    at getDependenciesFromPodfileLock (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/link-pods/getDependenciesFromPodfileLock.js:63:58)
    at warnAboutPodInstall (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/link/warnAboutPodInstall.js:43:67)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:80:36)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:23)
    at Command.listener (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:237:24)
    at Object.run (/Users/mine/Documents/code/js/emps_fe6/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:184:11)
```

Comment: Why not `pod install`

Comment: `pod install` did not work.

Answer (score 24):

First install the cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then run the below command on root folder

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ../ && react-native run-ios
```

Comment: `gem install cocoa pods` is fine. However `pod install` under `/ios` has error. `Command `config` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.` The error is a little confusing. 

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!.`

Comment: I removed the cocoa pods gem and reinstalled it again. Also ran `npm install`. The error is the same.

Comment: can you please use the yarn instead of npm

Comment: I usually use yarn install. the problem is the same.

Answer (score 20):

Step 1:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Step 2:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ../ && react-native run-ios
```

If you still get error while installing pods continue the below steps.

Step 3: Put this in console ->

```
xcrun -k --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
```

if the answer is

```
xcrun:_ error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
```

then put this:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Then install pod again

Comment: The command "sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app" give me the error:invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app'

Comment: @EdwardRamos Me too.

Comment: @Samim Hakimi, Thank you, it's run for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I solve the problem using bellow approach.

Navigate to iOS folder and then run bellow command:

**pod update**

pod update command will update all dependency and generate a **"Podfile.lock"** file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by jumping into the ios folder and running:

> pod update

Doing this directly in the ios folder resulted in the generation of Podsfile.lock

Changing out of ios into the main directory I was able to then launch the app on an IOS simulator using:

> npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many solutions. But finally tried something logical. I don't know why i didn't tried first :)

`pod install` doesn't work.It changes nothing. The problem is "Podfile" is there but not "Podfile.lock". Thats the problem. When we try install again, it is doing nothing because Podfile is there.

Solution is removing "Podfile" then `pod install` again. Then you will see both files "Podfile" and "Podfile.lock". After many hours of struggling, this was the solution for me and i have tried many thing :) Good luck to you all.

Comment: Both installing and updating with detailed commands were already recommended in previous answers

Comment: Yep, that was recommended and not worked :) there is one difference in my doing. I do that install command after delete podfile first. In my case, ıf podfile is exist, then install function do no change. My problem was continue. When i delete podfile from ios folder and use install command, then it worked perfectly

Comment: can install pod('pod install') without Podfile?

Comment: I wish i could remember and answer immediately but i have stopped deal with flutter for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody **with Mac M1** that nothing worked and still having the problem.
They actually say at the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#installing-an-ios-simulator-in-xcode) you need to run those commands

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

when it ends will tell

```
[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Pod installation complete! There are 55 dependencies from the Podfile and 46 total pods installed.
```

if you go and now run  `pod install` you will notice the deference

Answer (score -1):

This solution would work when you are trying to START a project, I don't know if it would help while you are in one and come across this issue.

Here is what I did:

- install node.js (unless you already have it downloaded)

  - TO CHECK: go into terminal and type: node -v
- install homeBrew (unless you already have it downloaded)

  - To download: go into terminal and type: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
  - remember to read what it says on the terminal to fully download it (there should be like two other commands you put in)
- install watchman, on terminal type: brew install watchman
- on terminal uninstall all your cocoapod stuff. Check how to with this link: https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine
- open up VScode
- type npx react-native init TestProject
- choose the method to install Cocoapods through Homebrew

This worked for me.